# AWS Dynamodb boto3 batch_get_item ProjectionExpression not working

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

With the Boto3 Python library, for the below code block while using `ProjectionExpression`, I am getting an error `Requested resource not found`.

When I do not use `ProjectionExpression`, it works but brings all columns.

```
sellerDict = dynamodb.batch_get_item(
    RequestItems={'Seller':
                   {'Keys': vq},
                   'ProjectionExpression': {
                   'Keys': [{'MobileNo': 'N'}, 
                            {'Offer': 'N'}]
                    }
                  }
)
```

Comment: Enhanced message structure and highlights

Answer (score 6):

The `ProjectionExpression` should be a string of attributes. In the below example, `yearkey` is a Number attribute, `title` is a String attribute and `info` is a Map attributes. I have just projected the `rating` attribute from `info` map.

```
RequestItems={
    'Movies': {
        'Keys': [
            {
                'yearkey': 2012,
                'title' : 'The Big New Movie 2012'
            },
        ],            
        'ConsistentRead': True,
        'ProjectionExpression': 'yearkey, title, info.rating'            
    }
},
```